# incorrect output when calculated

Tags: c, math, calculation

So im a beginner to the programming world and i'm currently learning to program in C and i can't seem to figure out what is going wrong with my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int
main ()
{
  float fees;
  float projcost;
  float num;

  printf ("Please enter the cost of your project\n");
  scanf ("%f", &projcost);

  if (projcost >= 10000)
{
    num = 0.10 * projcost;
    fees = num;
}
  else if (projcost >= 10001 || projcost <= 100000)
{
    num = 1000 + ((projcost - 10000) * 0.05);
  fees = num;
}  
    else (projcost >= 100001);
{    
    num = 6000 + ((projcost - 100000) * 0.03);
    fees = num;
}
    printf ("\nYour fees have totaled to %.2f", fees);

    return 0;
  }
```

If i use a number that is lower than 100,000 i get a completely different answer to what i calculate myself. i believe my calculations are correct so i don't understand what is the issue. i have been trying to input 7000 but it outputs 3210 when the answer is supposed to be 700. can anyone help?

Comment: You should adopt a conventional and consistent coding style early on - your brace placement is all over the place. Please also note that `int main()` has always been obsolete style and this might no longer work in upcoming C23 - always use `int main (void)`. Also please note that writing `int` on a line of its own before `main(void)` is rather unconventional style - some people use that style and I won't agree of pros/cons here, but you should know that the style you are using is not the most common one.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. The first condition should be inverted, otherwise the later ones won't be taken:

   ```
    if (projcost <= 10000)
   ```
2. The second condition should have a logical and instead of a logical or, otherwise it will always be true:

   ```
    else if (projcost >= 10001 && projcost <= 100000)
   ```
3. On the last branch:

   ```
    else (projcost >= 100001);
   ```

   You're missing an `if` and have an incorrectly placed semicolon. Fix that:

   ```
    else if (projcost >= 100001)
   ```

   However, since it's the last branch you're better to simply remove the condition:

   ```
    else
   ```
4. Because you're using floating point, the conditions that you listed don't actually cover all the possible inputs. For example, if the input is `10000.5`, then your logic will do something that you didn't expect (what exactly depends on which of the above fixes you apply). A simpler way of writing this logic would be:

   ```
    if (projcost <= 10000)
        fees = ...;
    else if (projcost <= 100000)
        fees = ...;
    else
        fees = ...;
   ```

   Which is, contrary to your code, is correct -- because exactly one branch will be taken, always.